# Maximum RAM capacity for the ASUS P5KPL-E

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade, ddr2

I'd like to revive an old PC. I'm wondering if the motherboard supports 4 GB of DDR2 RAM or a total of 8 GB of RAM.

This is an online accessible version of the OEM's manual: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mssDtkbEDrJFKsG1eA_aZEIkqU44S6L/view?usp=sharing

I've got it from here: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPLE/HelpDesk_Manual/

The **chart 1.7.2.** seems ambiguous to me. I don't understand if they meant 2GB per channel or 2GB per slot.

Here's my current RAM (Extracted from Speccy): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bov9gAcyxA4pzPMIBYks07CU8oWUxaiI7eGKxxP6lD0/edit?usp=sharing

Right now it seems to me that the capacity of this motherboard is 4GB and I should get another 2x1GB to fill the other two slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 GB Max according to the Manual.

Manual says max 2GB/channel. That's either 2 modules (of 2 GB) = 4 GB Max in Dual Channel Mode.